# Difference in compilation of a vbcode in cscript command and visual studio

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code in visual basic , which I am running through visual studio .

```
    Module Module1

        Sub Main()



            On Error GoTo errorHandler
            Dim oLapp As Object
            Dim oItem As Object

            oLapp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
            oItem = oLapp.createitem(0)
            '
            With oItem
                .Subject = "A MAIL"
                .To = "an_email_id@outlook.com"
                .body = "2018 RUSSIA IS OURS"
                .Send
            End With
            Console.Write("KROOOOOOOOSSSSSS")
            Console.Read()
            'Set oLapp = Nothing
            'Set oItem = Nothing

    errorhandler:
            Console.Write("jkjk")
        End Sub

End Module
```

This code is purported to send an email through outlook . However , I thought of doing this through command prompt and I got to know about "cscript" command which is used to run VB scripts in windows command prompt .

So , I put the following code in an notepad file and saved it with .vbs extension . Then when I tried calling this file using cscript , I got an error . 
It said syntax error at line 7 , col23 .

That line turns out to be :

```
On Error goto Errhandler
```

As such I commented that line out and tried running again and got an error again in line 8 , stating "expected end of statement .

So , I thought cscript might still be supporting "set" and "let" and hence put set in line 8 and I got the same error again .

So , is there any difference in the compilation of visual basic code in both these places . What will be the equivalent code of the code presented here that can be run via cscript and perform the task of sending an email through outlook .

Comment: VB is not VBScript, there are many differences between the two languages, one of them being that VBScript doesn't support `on error goto`. However, it does support `on error resume next`, and then you can check the `Err.Number` variable after every statement that can fail.

Comment: Interestingly, `On Error GoTo 0` is supported syntax in VBScript (it essentially reverses `On Error Resume Next`). Also, unassigned variables are `Empty` and are equal to 0, but `On Error GoTo Errhandler` (if `Errhandler` is `Empty` or `On Error GoTo Empty` will both produce a syntax error.

Comment: @Llangstorm  : Great to know these differences . Thnaks a a lot. Both of you